# Struts2 / css in textfield

Tags: html, jsp, struts2, struts-tags

I am beginning with struts2 programming and I wondered how I could do the following thing. I have this struts code in a form :

```
<s:textfield name="aName"/>
```

And I had this html code before using struts2 :

```
<input id="aLogin" type="text" class="form-control" name="username" value="" placeholder="something" required autofocus>
```

How could I "merge" these two lines to do the same html code but using my struts2 code ?

Comment: They have a different name, how would you like to merge them?

Answer (score 1):

In Struts tags, `class` ans `style` becomes `cssClass` and `cssStyle`; in old versions of Struts, `required` was an attribute indicating when to put the `*` mark, now changed to `requiredLabel` to avoid overriding the HTML5 required attribute. Other HTML5 attributes like `placeholder` and `autofocus` can be set because Textfield tag *Allows Dynamic Attributes*.

Then in your case:

```
<s:textfield id = "aLogin" 
           name = "aName" 
       cssClass = "form-control" 
          value = ""
    placeholder = "something" 
       required
      autofocus />
```

For other info, refer to the [official `<s:textfield/>` documentation](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/textfield.html)

Answer (score 0):

name should be same as that of bean variable,therefore,

```
<s:textfield name="username"/>
```

this will work, only if you have setUsername method in your action class.