# HTML autofocus does not work as a Struts2 textfield attribute

Tags: html, struts2

I appears to me that according to the answer at [Autofocus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27212433/struts2-css-in-textfield) the following code should set the focus on the `imageName` div.

```
<div class="grid-4">
     <s:textfield name="imageName" id="imageName" autofocus  />
</div>
```

But the autofocus does not appear in the generated html.

```
<div class="grid-4">
    <input type="text" name="imageName" value="" id="imageName"/>
</div>
```

Comment: it's not a supported attribute for struts2 tags. you can add it thru jquery afterwards though.

Comment: That is what I wound up doing.

Comment: which struts2 version ?

Comment: Version struts-2.3.dtd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the autoFocus attrribue is not supported by struts2 tag lib you can use workaround here.

In the JSP or in the external JS file you can add this jQuery script.

```
$( function(){

    $( '#imageName ).focus();    
} );
```